# Xpath to get nodes with distinct values(removing trailing and leading spaces)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xalan

I have an XML document in which I am trying to select nodes having distinct values with leading and trailing spaces removed.

I am using following `Xpath` and it is working:

```
ROW[COUNTRY[not(text() = following::ROW/COUNTRY[text()])]]
```

But when I am using `normalize-space(text())` in above `xpath` then the results returned are not correct.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <ROW>
        <COUNTRY>
            <![CDATA[USA]]>
        </COUNTRY>
        </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COUNTRY>
            <![CDATA[ USA]]>
        </COUNTRY>
    </ROW>
</ROOT>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ROW[COUNTRY[not(normalize-space(text()) = following::ROW/COUNTRY[normalize-space(text())])]]">
    <tr>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(./COUNTRY)"></xsl:value-of>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: You should include the XML and XSL used in the actual text of this question and not link to it. This will make this question and answer much more valuable in the future should the links stop to function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Muenchian grouping:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="group" match="ROW" use="normalize-space(COUNTRY)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ROW[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', normalize-space(COUNTRY))[1])]">
    <tr>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(./COUNTRY)"></xsl:value-of>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```